# How to identify the cells from the sumproduct formula result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I would first like to apologize if this question has already been posted and answered numerous times but I was unable to find the right wording for my question to find a thread that matched.

I have a Sumproduct formula with multiple criteria that helps identify the number of issues I have on the main spread sheet. I got the number of issues, however now I would like to identify the cells meeting this criteria. Is there any way to do this?

To further explain my intention, the main tab on my spread sheet is a report with many different columns that would need to be filtered several different ways each time in order to catch the exceptions we are looking for. I am trying to avoid this manual process by creating a new tab to show these exceptions without having to look for them and leave cause for any user/human error where something could potentially be missed. In a new tab, I used several formulas (like the one below) to determine the number of different exceptions we need to catch, however I am wondering if there is a way to also identify these specific cells that the exceptions fall in so that the user can immediately locate and correct it.
 For example: 2 issues identified; B10 and B26. (Or more specifically, if possible, the contents of that given cell?)

Sumproduct:
 =SUMPRODUCT(--(May!C2:C452="FHA"),--(May!Z2:Z452<>""),--(May!AB2:AB452<>""),--(May!AC2:AC452=""))

Note: I have also tried to achieve this by using conditional formatting using the formula above, however the issue that I run into with that approach is that the entire row gets highlighted instead of the specific cells matching the criteria from the formula. I am open to a solution with this as well if it is an easier approach.

I hope I am getting across what I am trying to do! Thank you in advance to whomever can help!

Comment: Look into Advanced Filter.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding an additional column to the *May* worksheet.  The new column would contain formulas like:

```
=(C2="FHA")*(Z2<>"")*(AB2<>"")*(AC2="")
```

If you AutoFilter on this new column, you will see all the contributors to the *SUMPRODUCT()* formula.

Answer (score 0):

Your *2 issues identified; B10 and B26* appears to refer to cells that have no bearing on what you seek to achieve so I may have misunderstood but suggest selecting A:AC and applying a CF formula rule of:

```
=AND($C1="FHA",$Z1<>"",$AB1<>"",$AC1="",OR(COLUMN()=3,COLUMN()=26,COLUMN()=28,COLUMN()=29))
```